# How do I execute a form with PHP after jQuery submit()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is the first time I'm submitting a form with jQuery.

I know how to submit a form with PHP only (without jQuery validation before).

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {

    ... // Do stuff here

}
```

What I need to know is, how do I call the `isset($_POST['name']` after I submit a form with jQuery.

This is what I tried, but didn't got it working:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <button type="button" name="submit-form" class="submit-button" href="#">Save</a>

</form>
```

After I click the save button, I do some validation with jQuery. If every field, which is mandatory, is filled out, I submut the form.

```
$(".submit-button").click(function() {
    if (fields arent filled out) {
       // Show error message 
    }
    if (fields are filled out) {
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I call with php the `$_POST['name']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<button>` tags do not submit a value - and you have no other values in your form to submit.

Alter your form to this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="submit" name="submit-form" class="submit-button" value='Save'>
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value='Hello'>

</form>
```

Then you will see the submitted values.

Also, your jQuery is submitting a 'class' of .myForm  which does not exist.
Change it to:

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

Then use this to process your posted values:  (note your missing close brackets)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {

    ... // Do stuff here

}
```

Comment: I don't use `<input type="submit">` because it will execute the form, although I'm validating it with jQuery. That's why I use a button (to trigger the jquery validation).

Comment: Then you could use a `<button>` tag, but you would need to close it properly and dont expect to see the `POST`'ed value.  Or - you could prevent submission of the form in jQuery, so that there is a fallback for if JS is unavailable.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with `<input type="submit">` and added a `e.preventDefault();` Now I'm searching how to undo the `e.preventDefault()` when validation is succesfull.

Comment: $(".myForm").submit();

Comment: Still don't get the post values with it : <

Comment: Buttons do not submit their value and there are no other values in your form to submit.  Read my answer.  Add yourself a test value - to prove that your form is submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("#myForm")[0].submit();
```

just raise the `.submit()` DOM event instead of calling the jquery's `.submit()`.

---

Also may be this could have been a typo, you are missing a `)` closing in if condition:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {
```

and you have missed a closing of the button:

```
<button type="button" name="submit-form" class="submit-button" href="#">Save</a>
//-----------------------------------you are closing an anchor--------------^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  $(".submit-button").click(function() {

     var name=$('#txtnameid').val();
     if(name=="")
     {
        // Show error message 
     }
     else
     {
        $(".myForm").submit();
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try below step:

- Before jquery code please include latest jquery file.
- Also use button id not button class.

Comment: _Also use button id not button class._ any specific reason for it.

Comment: This is not an answer.. ..or helpfull.. ..especially when there are already a number of perfectly good answers..

Answer (score -2):

```
$(":input").each(function() {
   if($(this).val() === "")
    alert("Empty Fields!!");
});
```

Comment: Although not incorrect - this does not answer the OP question.